# Gap after table in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I notice that there is some gap after my table. See the following snapshot:

[image: http://i39.tinypic.com/x3e4vd.jpg]

My LaTeX code is:

```
\begin{table}[htb]  
\caption{Error rates VS training size in AdaBoosted stump, SVM and kNN. \label{tab:examplecount8000errerrplot}}  
\begin{center}  
\begin{tabular}{c c}  
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{../boost.eps}   
&  
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{../svm.eps}   \\    
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{../knn.eps}   
& \\    
\end{tabular}  
\end{center}  
\end{table}     
%  
\subsection{Feature Numbers}
```

Is the gap normal or how can I reduce the gap to be normal?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Instead of centering the tables with the {center} environment, try to use the \centering macro. I should be something like

```
\begin{table}
\centering
...
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 10):

If [Charles's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685152/gap-after-table-in-latex/2685288#2685288) and [midtiby's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685152/gap-after-table-in-latex/2685449#2685449) answers don't fix it for you and you *must* adjust it (because, for instance the margin lady won't pass your dissertation until you do), you can diddle the lengths

- `\floatsep`
- `\textfloatsep`
- `\intextsep`

(and their two column brethren) which [adjust the spacing around and between floats](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/squeeze.html). In this case I believe you want `\textfloatsep`.

But do what Charles and midtiby said first, and consider Bears' advice as well.

Comment: This very good advice because it affects all floats with one single directive and thus one doesn't need to go around adding `\vspace` to every single float.

Answer (score 9):

You can always fix vertical spacing by emitting a vskip command, say `\vskip{-1em}`, in vertical mode, such as before the \section.  Bears is right: delay worrying about layout as late as possible.  There should be a saying about premature formatting...

The table would look more attractive to me if the caption was at the bottom.  The matter of appearance would be as much what is the proportion of space above and below the caption as the total amount of space.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but using `\vspace{-1em}` did.

Comment: @AlexReinking - If you are puzzled by the failure of my answer, it might be useful for you to ask it as a question, allowing the code to be discussed.  My guess is that Latex handles the switch to vertical mode more smartly with \vspace than \vskip, but I would have to see an MGE to be confident.  If you do ask a question, link to it in a comment here.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\raggedbottom`

```
\begin{table}
\centering
...
\end{table}

\raggedbottom
```

Answer (score 3):

*Undeleted answer, since this was referred to by dmckee.    I'm generally against fiddling about with the way you express content: better live with the unwanted space, change things in the style files (per dmckee's suggestion), change what you want to express (like where captions are), or put in pure band-aid (like vspace).  So I don't like this answer, since terminating every row of a tabular with a `\\` makes them easier to maintain, like ending C blocks with a semicolon.*

Delete the last `\\` in the tabular environment.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your tables: `\setlength\belowcaptionskip{-20pt}`